# How to get previous date records in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, amazon-athena

I am Left joining two tables Table 1 and Table 2 on basis of invoice date & created date and also sales office 
Table 1 has invoice date , sales office and other columns
Table 2 has created date , price and other columns
so i want invoice date from table 1 and price  from table 2 and for invoice date not present in created date of table 2 , I need price of previous created date from table 2 next to invoice date in output

Table 1

```
invoice date    sales office 
01-04-2019  ABC 
02-04-2019  ABC 
04-04-2019  ABC 
06-04-2019  ABC
```

Table 2

```
created date    sales office    price
01-04-2019  ABC          10
02-04-2019  ABC          20
05-04-2019  ABC          30
07-04-2019  ABC          30
```

Output

```
Invoice date    New date    price
01-04-2019  01-04-2019  10
02-04-2019  02-04-2019  20
04-04-2019  02-04-2019  20
06-04-2019  05-04-2019  30
```

Comment: Join 2 tables based on salesoffice

Answer (score 0):

If you want the most recent price for each invoice, then you can use a lateral join or correlated subquery:

```
select i.invoicedate, p.createddate, p.price
from invoices i outer apply
     (select top (1) p.*
      from prices p
      where p.salesoffice = i.salesoffice and
            p.createddate <= i.invoicedate
      order by p.createddate desc
     ) p;
```

In other databases, you can use window functions:

```
select ip.*
from (select i.invoicedate, p.createddate, p.price,
             row_number() over (partition by i.invoicedate order by p.createddate desc) as seqnum
      from invoices i join
           prices p
           on p.salesoffice = i.salesoffice and
              p.createddate <= i.invoicedate
     ) ip
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: @NoopurMehrotra Make an effort! There is no such error message in tsql. If you encounter an error, you should post the complete error message. And since no one has your schema, no one can test any suggestion - you have some responsibility here for providing accurate and useful information, and for writing tsql, and for correcting minor syntax errors. If you are not using sql server, then clarify your environment and correct your tags.